# dotnet build --- output an error for each file containing a specific string

Tags: .net, build, task

I am trying to create a Before Build task in a .csproj that will output an error for each file in a Path (and subfolders) if the file contains a "specific string".
The project is built with "dotnet build" cli command.
Has anyone done something like this before?

**More details:** I am building a `dacpac` for a database with a SDK project `<Project Sdk="MSBuild.Sdk.SqlProj/2.6.0">`.

**Problem:** the beautiful `dotnet build` (and the corresponding MsBuild tasks behind it) are silently failing to include in the `dacpac` any stored procedure that has a `CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [schema].[sp_name]`. It works just fine for a simple `CREATE PROCEDURE`.

**Ask:** I would prefer to avoid the silent failure with an error at build time (pipelines). I know a string search for `CREATE OR ALTER` is not ideal, but it will do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to come up with a half-decent solution:

```xml
<Target Name="CheckCreateOrAlter" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
        <Exec Command='findstr /I /S /N /C:"create or alter" /D:".\Database" *.sql' ConsoleToMSBuild="true" IgnoreExitCode="true">
            <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="OutputOfExec" />
        </Exec>
        <Error Condition="'$(OutputOfExec)' !='.\Database:'" Text="CREATE OR ALTER IS NOT ALLOWED: $(OutputOfExec)" />
    </Target>
```

This will not list individual errors for each file, but rather one error for all occurrences.
I don't want to create a CLI-tool or a MsBuild task so, as you can see, I am  using `findstr` utility. This starts the output by listing the directory searched. Therefore, if the output is just the directory, then no files have been found to contain the string. That is why the condition on error is `'$(OutputOfExec)' !='.\Database:'`.

It may not be the prettiest thing, but it gets the job done.